# How to fix this error "Syntax Error" while running CLI command

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a CLI command using Nodejs,

I am using npm link to test my code locally first, and I put my command in the bin section
you can see my **package.json** below,
and the **cli.js** is containing only console.log 
when I am trying to test **"validate-markets-cli"** in my cmd I got a popup windows containing this error,

- Error: 'console' is not defined.
- Code: 800A1391.
- Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error.

Here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "validate",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "cli.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node cli"
},
"bin": {
    "validate-markets-cli": "./cli.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.19.0",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
}
}
```

and this is my cli.js

```
console.log('test test');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this line **"#!/usr/bin/env node"**
at cli.js and it worked